# iOS safari - check if permission granted for device motion

Tags: javascript, ios, web

On iOS Safari, we must request permission to access device motion data as follows:

```
if (typeof DeviceMotionEvent.requestPermission === 'function') {
  DeviceMotionEvent.requestPermission()
    .then(permissionState => {
      if (permissionState === 'granted') {
        window.addEventListener('devicemotion', () => {});
      }
    })
    .catch(console.error)
  ;
} else {
  // Device is not iOS 13+, no permission requests are neccessary
}
```

This code (the permission request) must run following a click interaction (this is a requirement on iOS). Because of this, I am displaying a button, that, when clicked, runs the above code to request permissions.

However, chances are the permission is already granted from when the user previously used my app, and so I would like to avoid showing this button.

How can I check if permission already granted?

Answer (score 0):

Check to see if the if `permissionState` is already set to true before doing anything.

```
var example
if (example != 'granted')   {
 if (typeof DeviceMotionEvent.requestPermission === 'function') {
   DeviceMotionEvent.requestPermission()
     .then(permissionState => {
       if (permissionState === 'granted') {
         window.addEventListener('devicemotion', () => {});
        example='granted';
       }
     })
     .catch(console.error)
   ;
 } else {
   alert('Device is not iOS 13+, no permission requests are necessary')
 }
}
```

Comment: Where is the `permissionState` variable coming from? You can only access it when you call `requestPermission()`, right?

Comment: I forgot that... maybe have a different variable that copies the value of `permissionState` and use that. See if that is not equal to granted

Comment: The problem is I cannot access `permissionState` until I `requestPermission()`. I cannot call `requestPermission()` unless it is from a click event. I'd like to determine if the permission is already granted from before without requiring the user to click.

Comment: This check only works if the permission was previously granted on the same page load. If I refresh the page or come back a day later, this will once again require user interactions. Perhaps I could store this value in localstorage, but this doesn't sound very safe because I assume users can remove permission at any time and then this value would become outdated.

Comment: Thanks for your help anyways :)

Comment: Did you find a solution to this?

Answer (score 0):

Still facing this today. A bit workaround seem to work for me:

```js
let x1 = 0, y1 = 0, z1 = 0, x2 = 0, y2 = 0, z2 = 0;
let permissionGranted = false;

const requestPermission = () => {
  if (typeof DeviceMotionEvent.requestPermission === 'function') {
    DeviceMotionEvent.requestPermission()
  }
}
// Call requestPermission first for devicemotion listener working (This will call silently because not being called inside an eventHandler)
requestPermission()

// Listen to motion events and update the position
window.addEventListener('devicemotion', function (e) {
  permissionGranted = true;
  x1 = e.accelerationIncludingGravity.x;
  y1 = e.accelerationIncludingGravity.y;
  z1 = e.accelerationIncludingGravity.z;
}, false);

// After 1s if still no data received from devicemotion event, just show Grant Button to click => Nomaly requestPermission
setTimeout(() => {
  if (!permissionGranted && typeof DeviceMotionEvent.requestPermission === 'function') {
    grantButton.style.display = "block";
    grantButton.addEventListener('click', requestPermission);
  }
}, 1000)
```

Comment: So essentially are you saying `requestPermission` will silently work outside event handler if permission is already granted?

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: @DavidCallanan yep, i mean no confirm popup at all, requestPermission() just for devicemotion listener working in case permission has been granted before.